# Laravel query whereRelation reffering wrong field

Tags: mysql, laravel

It's a bit weird i'm using whereRelation in my queries but not reffering the field i wanted

my table structure like so

Orders table :

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('shipment_id');
    $table->integer('qty');
    $table->string('item_code');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Shipments table :

```
Schema::create('shipments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('shipment_id')->unique(); // this reffering the ID from shipping lines
    $table->string('delivery_plan');
    $table->string('eta');
    $table->string('destination');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The relations

```
/**
* Get the order associated with its shipments.
*/
public function shipments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Shipment::class);
}

/**
* Get the shipment associated with its order.
*/
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(order::class);
}
```

My query :

```
$orders = Order::whereRelation('shipments', function($query) {
    $query->whereIn('destination', ['USA', 'CANADA']);
})
->leftJoin('shipments', 'orders.shipment_id', '=', 'shipments.shipment_id')
->addselect(DB::raw('SUM((qty)) as total_qty'))
->groupBy('orders.sales_id')
->groupBy('orders.item_code');
```

The query result from relation :

```
where exists (select * from `shipments` where `orders`.`shipment_id` = `shipments`.`id`)
```

The query result i wanted :

```
where exists (select * from `shipments` where `orders`.`shipment_id` = `shipments`.`shipment_id`)
```

Its refer to **shipments.id** instead of **shipments.shipment_id** How can i solve this ?

Comment: show us `model` code

Comment: @atma what code ? already provided the relation method from Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laravel, default `primary key` for `model` is `ID`, either that you need to add below code in `model` [Eloquent, Primary Keys](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#primary-keys)

```
protected $primaryKey = 'your_pk';
```

and if your relationships not use `ID` as `key`, you need to add `parameter` in relationship function [Eloquent, Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships)

```
public function shipments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Shipment::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}

public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(order::class, 'foreign_key', 'owner_key');
}
```

Comment: I see,i thought if i define the relationship manually on the query it won't be a problem even i didn't define it on relationship